# How to change Viewport background color

Tags: 3d-view, interface, grease-pencil

I would like to draw on a dark gray or black background, but I do not yet know how to change the background color of the 3D viewport in *Grease Pencil* mode.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Shading and change the color

Hope that helps.

[image]

Good Luck

Comment: Very helpful. Suppose you want a transparent background afterwards, before exporting to image sequence. What do you do?

Comment: Go to Render >> Film >> Transparent

Comment: Thank you very much. That helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can control this also in the *World Properties* section.
[image]

Comment: It hasn't really changed, in the shading you can control the background for the viewport as well as the world.  Additionally you can do this in the world settings.

Comment: @susu That might be true, but it's definitely moved from where the other clip showed it was located at and that is confusing. Which is why I think forums like these shouldn't necessarily post clips/videos/images about it - as they get outdated **really** quickly. It's my honest opinion that answers like these **should** reference to the manual page upstream when referencing a solution, so that users can follow the changes. Dead links is an issue, but that's more for blog posts etc. Product manuals should be alive during the lifetime of the product at least.